# Fresh 22.04 Keyboard Input Lag / Non-responsive Touchpad

Tags: drivers, keyboard, touchpad

I just fresh installed 22.04 on my laptop and the laptop keyboard input is delayed in all applications.  If type too many characters too quickly my touchpad actually stops responding as well.  The only way I have found to regain touchpad functionality is to close the laptop and put it to sleep.

As far as I can tell this is not just an Ubuntu issue, I tried installing Fedora and had **the exact same issues**.

This is a brand new laptop, Lenovo Thinkbook 13s with AMD 6800U, 16GB of DDR5 RAM.  Because it is so new I am thinking maybe the drivers just aren't available, but I wanted to post here and see if anyone had similar experiences or hopefully some answers.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. It happens randomly, though, always after fresh system startup.

Answer (score 1):

Just identified problem - need to upgrade kernel (mine version was 5.5.X) upgraded to 6.1.0-060100rc1-generic and this problem disappeared.

Full instructions how to on: https://sypalo.com/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu