# Ubuntu 22.04, touchpad click and button click not working all the time

Tags: 22.04, touchpad

I've checked this one before I tried anything: [Fresh 22.04 Keyboard Input Lag / Non-responsive Touchpad](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1428836/fresh-22-04-keyboard-input-lag-non-responsive-touchpad) However, my kernel is already at 6.2.0-37-generic

I've installed ubuntu on my laptop after it got back from service - keyboard had issues. However, I immediately noticed that touchpad clicks don't work always (almost miss every other click). Same seem to be true for physical touchpad button clicks.

I have Lenovo T14s, 1st gen.

I tested the touchpad in bios btw and it seem to be working fine (I was suspecting that guys who serviced it did something wrong).

Where can I even start?

Thanks!